# How to use php ArrayCachePool?

Tags: php, api, caching

So I'm trying to use this library for caching. https://github.com/php-cache/array-adapter

This is the sample code from documentation.

```
$pool = new ArrayCachePool();
$item = $pool->getItem('key')->set('datakkk');
$pool->save($item);
dd($pool->get('key'));
```

I want to store the token for some 3 minutes and if that token expires I want to make an auth API call. If it is not expired it will call the whatever endpoint it has provided.

I have done most of the part just I'm stuck between how to cache the token.
Because it does get stored when I call the above code but it gets cleared for the next API call. Tried singletone pattern but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayCache` does **not** store any data **between** requests. It is supposed to store data during single script execution. So, when your script ends - all data from `ArrayCache` is **lost**.

To store data **between** requests use another cache engine, not `ArrayCache`.

Comment: That totally makes sense. I was so confused about that. Thanks.